# Eigendecomposition of a matrix with a variable

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have an issue with a decomposition of a matrix $B$ that is positive semidefinite and that depends on a parameter $x$. Writing $\lambda_i\geq0$ the eigenvalues and $\psi_i$ the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors, I have $B = \sum_i \lambda_i \psi_i \psi_i^\dagger$. Then I would like to rewrite $B$ as $B = \sum_i  \phi_i \phi_i^\dagger$, with $\phi_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}\psi_i$.

Concerning the Mathematica code: the matrix $B$ is defined as the tensor product of the following matrix $A$:

```
A = {{1, 0, 0, 1 - 2x}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {1 - 2x, 0, 0, 1}};
B = KroneckerProduct[A, A, A];
```

Once having defined matrix $B$, I compute the normalized eigenvectors and eigenvalues of it:

```
EigenVec = Map[Normalize, Eigenvectors[B]];
EigenVal = Eigenvalues[B];
```

Then, I define

```
phi[i_] := Sqrt[EigenVal[[i]]] EigenVec[[i]];
```

and I should be done. Yet, when checking if the rewriting of $B$ is working, I find that it is not, indeed

```
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerProduct[phi[i],Conjugate[Transpose[phi[i]]]], {i, 1, 64}] - B] // MatrixForm
```

output a non-zero matrix that has some dependency on the parameter $x$. I checked that there were no crossings between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as well as other consistency checks, without managing to understand what is wrong with that...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `Eigensystem`, ordering in not guaranteed to match if you use `Eigenvectors` and `Eigenvalues` separately

Comment: I tried as well with ```Eigensystem```, but I had the same kind of issue. I don't think it is coming from orderings of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your eigenvectors in `EigenVec` are normalized but not orthogonal to each other, as you can see using

```
Table[Dot[Conjugate[EigenVec[[i]]],EigenVec[[j]]],{i,1,64},{j,1,64}]
```

Your matrix `B` has  multiple eigenvalues, which can lead to this problem. You should get the correct result using

```
EigenVec=Orthogonalize[Eigenvectors[B]];
```

**Remark.** Note that your eigenvalues are only nonnegative if

```
Reduce[Thread[EigenVal>=0]]
(* 0 <= x <= 1 *)
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right, this is working now! Thank you !
And I agree, I forgot to mention that $x \in [0,1]$.